# The view mysiteapp.views.addpost didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django, django-forms

> my `views.py` file  i just try to update form data form dashboard so i'm not getting what's going wrong  to the code can someone  please help  me to solve

```py
def addpost(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            forms = addpostForm(request.POST)
            if is_valid():
                forms.save()
                forms = addpostForm()
            else:
                forms = addpostForm()
            return render(request, 'addpost.html', {'form': forms})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('login')
```

> `addpost.html` file

```html
<form action ='' method='POST'>
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{form.as_p}}
   <input type='submit' class='btn btn-success btn-sm' value ='Add' >
   <input type='submit' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' value ='Cancel' >
</form>
```

> my `forms.py`

```py
class addpostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = post
        fields = ['title','desc']
        labels ={'title':'Title','desc':'Description'}
        widgets = {'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":'form-control'}),'desc':forms.Textarea(attrs={"class":'form-control'}),}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method did not *return* a HTTP response in case of a *GET* request. You should unindent the else and thus construct a new form in case of a GET request and render the page.

For a successful POST request, you normally *redirect* to a view (that can be the same view), to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* architectural pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import redirect

@login_required
def addpost(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        forms = addpostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if is_valid():
            forms.save()
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        forms = addpostForm()
    return render(request, 'addpost.html', {'form':forms})
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).